# Question about conjugation of permutation

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I am doing some homework and want to be sure I understand correct:

Permutation $\sigma=(12345)(67)(89)$ in $S_9$

Determine if $\sigma^{2002}$ and $\sigma^4$ are conjugated:

I have $\sigma^{2002}=(13524)$ and $\sigma^4=(54321)$

Thus, I have $\tau=(1534)$ and therefore they are indeed conjugated as $\tau \sigma^{2002}\tau^{-1}=\sigma^4$

Is this a correct result?

Comment: yep, looks good

Comment: Both have the same cycle type, and hence are conjugated. Of course, making this explicit is even better.